# Use different IP on telnetlib.Telnet, instead of chosen by default one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnetlib

I need to make a telnet conversation and this brought me to use official *telnetlib* library, widely explained here: [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html).
The machine that actually use this software has several IPs, but it seems *telnetlib* does not provide an easy - or evident, at least - way to change my IP used in the handshake phase of telnet conversation.

Anyone has some useful information about that?

Comment: do you mean server has many IPs ? But does server use FTP on all this IPs ?

Comment: Yup, servers owns 5 IPs, plus the loopback one.
I just want to decide the one to be used to create the _telnet_ conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source to telnetlib is here, and it appears it does not provide any way to specify the IP of the socket, leaving it up to the OS to select, which will result in the 'default' network interface.

```
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
```

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/telnetlib.py#l227

The `create_connection()` signature is:

```
socket.create_connection(address[, timeout[, source_address]])
```

> If supplied, source_address must be a 2-tuple (host, port) for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting. If host or port are ‘’ or 0 respectively the OS default behavior will be used.
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

You could copy the telnetlib.py and modify the `create_connection()`

I have not tested this! But it could be like this on l227

```
self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout, (src_host, src_port))
```

or even add a keyword arguments to the open() call to pass in the desired interface info.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed.